# Code listings of O'reilly books

Tags: listings, code

What are the O'Reilly code listing configurations for their books about computer science? Following is an example of such code formatting.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in latex? If so, consider using the `listings` package, linked to [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings?lang=en).
It wont look that that right out the gate, but its very configurable

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm aware of the listing, but actually I was looking for the listing configurations that can get as close as those on O'reilly as shown on the example above.

Comment: @mathssoso: What language is used in the book?

Comment: @Werner: It's Scala, but several other books use Python, Java.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. As asked, this is either too broad or unanswerable. If O'Reilly doesn't make their source available (do they even use TeX?) then there is no such configuration. But as others have said, the `listings` package supports many languages out of the box, and adding associated colouring is not that difficult. Alternatively there is also  `pygments` which can do similar things. So then make a sample document using one of those, using the appropriate language definition file, and then we can help you with the specifics.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Thank you, could you check my post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584071/configure-minted-style-in-latex-for-code-highlighting).